# Autoscroll to div after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am trying to get the page I am working on to smooth scroll to a headline in a div after about a minute on page load (I know this is a cardinal sin in UX).
I came up with this but so far, it hasn't worked.

jQuery

```
        $('body').delay(5000) 
        .animate({
          'scrollTop': $('#target').offset().top
        }, 5000); 
      });
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" >
 <div class="row" id="target">
            
            <div class="section-heading px-3 pl-4 pr-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center" >
              <h1 class="display-4" id="tap">Headline</h1>   
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="image" width="173" height="173">
              <h2 class="value-heading">small heading</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>      
            </div>
    
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="image" width="173" height="173">
              <h2 class="value-heading">small heading</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
      
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="image" width="173" height="173">
              <h2 class="value-heading">small heading</h2>
              <p class="value-description">info</p>
      
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
    

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change code like this, `.animate({ 'scrollTop': $('#target').parent().offset().top }, 5000);` .you can try it

Comment: This didn't work. When the page loaded, it was already at that div. :/

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in plain JavaScript.

```js
let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#target').scrollIntoView();
}, 5000);

(function() {
  document.querySelector('#bottom').scrollIntoView();
})();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.height {
  height: 5rem;
}

.height > h1,
.height > h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.height.gray {
 background-color: silver;
}

.height.red {
 background-color: red;
}

.height.green {
 background-color: green;
}

.height.blue {
 background-color: blue;
}

.height.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.height.gray {
 background-color: gray;
}

.height.brown {
 background-color: brown;
}

.height.orange {
 background-color: orange;
}

.height.lavender {
 background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<div class="height gray"><h1>Main Header</h1></div>
<div class="height red" id="target"><h2>Header 1</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 2</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 3</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 4</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 5</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 6</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 7</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 8</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 9</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 10</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 11</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 12</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 13</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 14</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 15</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 16</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 17</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 18</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 19</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 20</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 21</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 22</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 23</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow">
  <h2>Header 24</h2>
  Wait 5 seconds for automatic scroll up
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let pos = $('#bottom').offset();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos.top, scrollLeft: pos.left});

  pos = $('#target').offset();
  $('html, body').delay(5000).animate({scrollTop: pos.top, scrollLeft: pos.left});
    
/*
// Or you can use this other way instead of the delay function if you want to.
  let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    let pos = $('#target').offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos.top, scrollLeft: pos.left});
  }, 5000);
*/
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.height {
  height: 5rem;
}

.height > h1,
.height > h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.height.gray {
 background-color: silver;
}

.height.red {
 background-color: red;
}

.height.green {
 background-color: green;
}

.height.blue {
 background-color: blue;
}

.height.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.height.gray {
 background-color: gray;
}

.height.brown {
 background-color: brown;
}

.height.orange {
 background-color: orange;
}

.height.lavender {
 background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="height gray"><h1>Main Header</h1></div>
<div class="height red" id="target"><h2>Header 1</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 2</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 3</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 4</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 5</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 6</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 7</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 8</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 9</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 10</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 11</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 12</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 13</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 14</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 15</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 16</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 17</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 18</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 19</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow"><h2>Header 20</h2></div>
<div class="height red"><h2>Header 21</h2></div>
<div class="height green"><h2>Header 22</h2></div>
<div class="height blue"><h2>Header 23</h2></div>
<div class="height yellow">
  <h2>Header 24</h2>
  Wait 5 seconds for automatic scroll up
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm only trying to scroll to a div once and not go back up. Would I simply remove 
'pos = $('#target').offset();
  $('html, body').delay(5000).animate({scrollTop: pos.top, scrollLeft: pos.left});' and change let pos = $('#bottom') to  let pos = $('#target') to make it work as I intend?

Comment: I figured it out. I just removed the bottom portion. :) Will this only do it once or will I need to add removeClass to prevent it from running again while the user is scrolling?

Comment: I tried to impliment this using your code with the code I posted above and it didn't work. It was actually sitting below the intended DIV on page load.

Comment: The way your HTML is set up the div with id="target" is already at the top, so of course the browser will show it at the top, so I added a scroll down at the beginning for you to see it scroll to the div#target.

Comment: I gave you code samples that work it's up to you to use your brain muscles to adjust it to make it work with your HTML, learn by doing.

Comment: There's what I remember from this website. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you. I found that my problem was that I posted my custom JS first (which is what my scroll was in) instead of jQuery first in my header. Check that first. Make sure you're not using the slim OR slim.min versions of jQuery as those files do not include animations! FYI you can change the name of the function if you'd like. Just make sure you change it in all three places in the code below (my function is named scrolltodiv).

The first number in the parenthesis is the speed of your animation. I have mine set at 2000 because I wanted it to go a bit slower. I wouldn't decrease that number too much as it can be jarring for users. The second number is the number of milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds). Google has a built in calculator if you search 'seconds to milliseconds.'

I'll go ahead and share the code that was given to me. I remember what it was like when I first started trying to learn jQuery (and JavaScript). I find it's much easier to code when you have exact examples and can reverse engineer them. Happy coding!

```
$(document).ready(function(scrolltodiv) {
    function scrolltodiv(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrolldiv").offset().top
            }, 2000); //Speed of animation

    }


    window.setTimeout( scrolltodiv, 55000 ); //Time in milliseconds
});
```