# Scroll to a div after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to smooth scroll to a div after about a minute on a page. I looked on here and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675133/autoscroll-to-div-after-a-few-seconds) but it did not help me as the person who gave the answer didn't really answer the person's question.

I'd prefer to use jQuery but I am open to JavaScript as well.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').delay(5000) 
        .animate({
      'scrollTop': $('#usp').offset().top
        }, 5000); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Something like this which is quite easy.
Just Create a function with some name and call it after few seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scrolltodiv(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
            }, 2000);

    }


    window.setTimeout( scrolltodiv, 5000 );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately this didn't work and it was well past the div on page load. I tried playing with the numbers a bit but it didn't work either. I'm still stumped over this scrolling thing.

Comment: Can you share your html and let me know your exact requirement. Also check your console for error.

Comment: I got your code to work on CP so I think I've attached the jQuery incorrectly.
Here's how I've attached it.

<head>
 <script src="js/autoscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>
</head>


 <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: I fixed it! I just realized I put my custom JS before jQuery. Oops. Thank you so much for your help! I'll mark your answer as correct since it's definitely right.

Comment: Great.. Now you will remember it for ages. Always put Jquey CDN above.

Comment: That was the first (and last) time I'll be doing that. Thank you again @ABHISHEK CHOUDHARY. I was able to pass this onto someone else here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
( function($){

setTimeout( function() {
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top
        // you can use $(".elementClass") but as ID should be unique, it would be better to use an element ID instead of classes
    }, 2000);
    // 2000 ms is the animation duration

}, 5000) 
// it scrolls to #elementID after 5000 ms = 5 secs

} )(jQuery);
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately (I was sure to remove the jQuery in the ending parenthesis) but thank you for posting your response. I wonder what my issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      animate("#idorclass" ,2000)
    }, 5000)
})

const animate = (idorclass, animval)=>{
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(idorclass).offset().top
 }, animval);
}
```

also dynamic function that you can reuse